# How to keep in same positions <h3> tag headline in css?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML codes with CSS to display 3 columns with the same width.
But when displaying `<h3>`, the topics does not display in the same positions. How can I display them with same positions?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100px;
}

.column2 {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: auto;
  height: 800px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <h2>Size & Weight</h2>

  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <h3>Weight </h3>
    <p>Approx. 255g</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">

  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column2" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <h2>General Features</h2>
    <!-- <p>Some text..</p> -->
  </div>
  <div class="column2" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <h3>Volume Control </h3>
    <p>Touch Sensor</p>

    <h3>Impedance (Ohm) </h3>
    <p>47 ohm (1kHz) (when connecting via the headphone cable with the unit turned on) , 16 ohm (1kHz) (when connecting via the headphone cable with the unit turned off)</p>


  </div>
  <div class="column2" style="background-color:#ccc;">
    <h3>Passive Operation</h3>
    <p>Yes</p>

    <h3>Frequency Response (Active Operation)</h3>
    <p>4Hz-40,000Hz</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you also upload your HTML here?

Comment: How does your code relate to an `<h3>`?

Comment: @ElmanHuseynov now you could see my html

Comment: @sign458 see my answer

Comment: I need keep same positions <h3> tags topics

Comment: can you draw what your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

I added padding:10px to the ".column2" and everything is looking in the same position,

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100px;
}

.column2 {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 800px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <h2>Size & Weight</h2>

  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <h3>Weight </h3>
    <p>Approx. 255g</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">

  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column2" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <h2>General Features</h2>
    <!-- <p>Some text..</p> -->
  </div>
  <div class="column2" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <h3>Volume Control </h3>
    <p>Touch Sensor</p>

    <h3>Impedance (Ohm) </h3>
    <p>47 ohm (1kHz) (when connecting via the headphone cable with the unit turned on) , 16 ohm (1kHz) (when connecting via the headphone cable with the unit turned off)</p>


  </div>
  <div class="column2" style="background-color:#ccc;">
    <h3>Passive Operation</h3>
    <p>Yes</p>

    <h3>Frequency Response (Active Operation)</h3>
    <p>4Hz-40,000Hz</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @sign458 specify please by screen what exactly is not working for you

Comment: I need my second and third column <h3> tag headings in same positions against the content <p> tags

Answer (score 0):

is in same position, but you need normalize the "height" of heading.
Try:

```
h2, h3 {
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: same result here